# GCC libm not working

Tags: c, linux

I have a c program that calls sin, cos, and acos. When I compile I get the following errors:

```
/tmp/ccDfW98S.o: In function `zip_search':
main.c:(.text+0xf30): undefined reference to `sin'
main.c:(.text+0xf45): undefined reference to `sin'
main.c:(.text+0xf66): undefined reference to `cos'
main.c:(.text+0xf7b): undefined reference to `cos'
main.c:(.text+0xf9c): undefined reference to `cos'
main.c:(.text+0xfc6): undefined reference to `acos'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I know this is common when you don't use the -lm gcc flag. I AM using this flag. I'm calling GCC like this:

```
gcc -o zipcode-server -lm main.c
```

When I compile on one of my computers this works fine. The only difference that I can think of is that this isn't working on x86_64 and the computer it does work on is i686. Both are Ubuntu. The file libm.a is present on the computer it isn't working on and I don't get any errors saying it can't be found. What could be causing this?

Comment: Could you please post the relevant portion of your code so we can help you with your problem?

Comment: Just for fun try: `gcc -o zipcode-server main.c -lm`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should put `-lm` after `main.c`

In general, if you have multiple libraries, they should be written in order of their usage. For example, if library `A` uses library `B`, you should have `-lA -lB`.

In your case, the object file that is the result of compilation of `main.c` uses library `m` and therefore `-lm` should come after it.

---

For the curious, this is mostly for efficiency reasons. With this scheme, the linker can resolve currently unknown symbols with every new library seen in the argument list, and picking up new unknown symbols from that library on the way. This means that the linker can visit the libraries one by one, and therefore match the unknown symbols against a small number of symbols provided by each library.

On the contrast, the linker could load in symbols from all libraries at once, and then start matching unknown symbols. In that case however, the linker needs to deal with a much greater number of symbols, increasing both the memory footprint and the execution time of the linker.

Since the libraries could always be declared to the linker in the proper order of their dependencies<sup>1</sup>, there is no reason for the linker to choose the inefficient way.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Libraries normally have a one-way relationship, in the sense that one uses the other.  Circular dependencies between libraries is rare, if at all existing, but it could still be used with this model by repeating certain libraries to be reinspected.</sub>

Comment: Well, it's not really needed to load all symbols at once.  All you need to do is have a multi-pass linker instead of a single-pass linker.  So it would walk all the libraries and resolve all the symbols, then if at the end there were still unresolved symbols it would walk the libraries again.  If you get to the end of a walk and you've got the same set of unresolved symbols at the end that you did at the beginning, you fail with undefined symbols.  However, that's not how any common linker today works.

Comment: @MadScientist, why walk the libraries multiple times when you can specify them in the right order and walk them once? That's just slower linking! (But point taken)

Comment: I didn't say it SHOULD be done that way.  I have no problem with the single-pass linker model virtually all linkers use today.  I just said that IF someone wanted to write a linker that didn't force a specific order, they don't have to load every symbol into memory.  They can just use multiple passes.