# eclipse build error in c project

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc

i use eclipse ide for c project on mac computer
i install usblib 
 `sudo brew install libusb`
and my program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libusb-1.0/libusb.h>
int main(void) {
    libusb_context **libcontext;
    int status = libusb_init(libcontext);
    if (status == 0) {
        printf("success");
    }
}
```

the libusb is at
[image]

when i build error

> 10:17:53 **** Build of configuration Debug for project testusb ****
>   make all  Building file: ../src/testusb.c Invoking: Cross GCC Compiler
>   gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -stdlib=libstdc++ -MMD -MP
>   -MF"src/testusb.d" -MT"src/testusb.o" -o "src/testusb.o" "../src/testusb.c" ../src/testusb.c:16:6: warning: unused variable
>   'status' [-Wunused-variable]
>           int status = libusb_init(libcontext);
>               ^ ../src/testusb.c:16:27: warning: variable 'libcontext' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
>           int status = libusb_init(libcontext);
>                                    ^~~~~~~~~~ ../src/testusb.c:15:29: note: initialize the variable 'libcontext' to silence this warning
>           libusb_context **libcontext;
>                                      ^
>                                       = NULL 2 warnings generated. Finished building: ../src/testusb.c   Building target: testusb
>   Invoking: Cross GCC Linker gcc -L/opt/local/lib -o "testusb" 
>   ./src/testusb.o    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>
>   "_libusb_init", referenced from:
>         _main in testusb.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to
>   see invocation) make: *** [testusb] Error 1

how to fix that?

[image]

Comment: It seems the library is not linked. Check your project setting.

Comment: i add the setting picture,but i don't know how to set it.this is my first use c program

Comment: see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050482/libusb-undefined-reference-to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks @Fang suggestion [Libusb undefined reference to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050482/libusb-undefined-reference-to)
i solve the problem.
first type

```
pkg-config --list-all
```

query all installed libraries,check libusb whether installed,
then type

```
pkg-config --libs libusb
```

link against the libusb i want to use

there should be the output

```
-lusb
```

then right click project properties->c/c++ Build->Setting->Cross GCC Linker Miscellaneous,type `-lusb-1.0`