# undefined reference to libusb using cyusb

Tags: c++, cypress, libusb-1.0

I have downloaded linux software of cypress SDK [EZ-USB FX3 Software Development Kit](http://www.cypress.com/documentation/software-and-drivers/ez-usb-fx3-software-development-kit). Inside `Cypress/cyusb_linux_1.0.5/src` there's many `.cpp` file that I compile with make and that work perfectly. I wanted to do my own cpp project so I copy the code of one of those files and tried to compile it using `CMakeLists.txt`. I have the following structure:

```
project/
├── include/
│   └── cyusb.h
├── src/
│   └── libcyusb.cpp
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── main.cpp
```

When I do:

```
$apt list --installed | grep -i libusb
libusb-1.0-0/bionic,now 2:1.0.21-2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libusb-1.0-0-dev/bionic,now 2:1.0.21-2 amd64 [installed]
```

However, following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050482/libusb-undefined-reference-to) I get no response doing `pkg-config --libs libusb` but I did find something with:

```
$pkg-config --libs libusb-1.0
-lusb-1.0
```

So I added it to my CMakeLists.txt and right now it looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(project)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
SET(GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS  "-lusb-1.0")
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS}")

file(GLOB SOURCES
        include/*.h
        src/*.cpp
        main.cpp
        )
add_executable(project ${SOURCES})
```

When I hit `make` I get:

```
[ 33%] Linking CXX executable project
CMakeFiles/project.dir/src/libcyusb.cpp.o: In function `libusb_get_descriptor':
/usr/include/libusb-1.0/libusb.h:1777: undefined reference to `libusb_control_transfer'
CMakeFiles/project.dir/src/libcyusb.cpp.o: In function `libusb_get_string_descriptor':
/usr/include/libusb-1.0/libusb.h:1799: undefined reference to `libusb_control_transfer'
CMakeFiles/project.dir/src/libcyusb.cpp.o: In function `device_is_of_interest(libusb_device*)':
project/src/libcyusb.cpp:157: undefined reference to `libusb_get_device_descriptor'
CMakeFiles/project.dir/src/libcyusb.cpp.o: In function `renumerate()':
project/src/libcyusb.cpp:208: undefined reference to `libusb_get_device_list'
project/src/libcyusb.cpp:219: undefined reference to `libusb_open'

[...] ETC [...] (you got the idea...)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the library with the standard CMake mechanism.

```
target_link_libraries(project usb-1.0)
```

The variable `GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS` is not used in normal builds.